# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(a_n-a_{n+1})}{a_{n+1}}=0$ if $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n/n$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Consider a sequence $(a_ n)$ of positive and monotonically decreasing terms for which $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n/n$ diverges and $a_ n\to 0$. I claim that that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(a_n-a_{n+1})}{a_{n+1}}=0.$$ 
I suspect that it's true (at least I can't find a counterexample) but I can't find a clean proof. Is there some theorem or test that might help out?

Comment: @Winther $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ converges, though.

Comment: *If* the limit exist and is non-zero then for large $n$ we have $\frac{Ca_{n+1}}{n} \simeq a_n - a_{n+1}$ and by summing up the right hand side telescopes and gives us that $\sum \frac{a_{n+1}}{n}$ converges which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: simply use $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ to see that the statement is wrong

Comment: @Alex *$\sum \frac1{n^2}$ converges, though.*

Comment: Perhaps interesting to note that if this ratio *does* converge to, say, $C>0$, then we can show that $a_n\sim n^{-C}$ (up to a constant factor). This doesn't cover the case where the ratio goes to infinity or doesn't converge at all, though I suspect that $a$'s monotonicity and decreasing nature might help here.

Comment: @sirfoga: plug in $\frac{1}{n}$ into the limit you have: it does not converge to 0

Comment: @Alex yup! but the serie $\sum \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ converges indeed, so the hypothesis is not satisfied, so we cannot conclude that the limit is $0$

Comment: @Winther You should post that comment as an answer, or I'll do it for you.

Comment: @Crostul Please go ahead and answer it. However the observation does not fully resolve the problem though: it might be that the sequence doesn't converge so a bit more work is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $a_n=\frac{1}{\log (n+1) \prod_{k^2\le n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$. Note that:

- $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$
- $a_n$ is bounded below by $\frac{1}{\log (n+1) \prod_{k\ge1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{\sinh\pi}\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}$
- $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{n}=\infty$ by comparison with, say, $\int_2^t\frac{1}{x\log x}dx$

Now, note that for $n=k^2$, $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)(1+\frac{1}{n})}$, whence the listed ratio at $(n-1)$ is:

$$(n-1)(\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}-1)=(n-1)\left(\frac{\log(n+1)(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\log(n)}-1\right)$$

Now, notice $\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}=1+\frac{1}{n\log(n)}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$, giving the ratio as:

$$\left(n-1\right)\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log(n)}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right)=(n-1)(\frac{1}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n\log(n)}))\to1$$

which offers a counterexample to the claim.

One can also note that for other $n$, the ratio is $n\left(\frac{\log(n+2)}{\log(n+1)}-1\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{\log (n)}\right)\to0$.

Comment: Thanks got your thoughts and suggestion. I'm not sure how to reconcile that with the comment from @Winther, that if the limit exists then the series converges. His argument seemed to work...

Comment: Well, in this case the ratio is (mostly) close to $0$, it just pops up to $\approx 1$ when $n$ is a square number. If the ratio is bounded below by a constant $>0$, then the series does end up convergent, so to find a counterexample you need something where the ratio isn't tending to 0, but isn't bounded away from 0.

Comment: This construction seems to work. You should probably add that $\frac{n(a_n - a_{n+1})}{a_{n+1}}$ does not converge by showing that the limit along $k=n^2+1$ (for example) is $0$. A typo: $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)(1+1/n)}$ instead of $\log(n-1)/\log(n)$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks, will amend the typo. Re: the non-convergence, the construction shows that it doesn't converge to 0, which is enough to offer a counter-example. Will add in some commentary to address in any case.

Comment: Yes, I see now! Thanks though I'm not very happy about the conjecture not being true - it would have been the final piece in a much larger puzzle. I'll have a think about how to revise the hypothsis to prevent such behavior.

Comment: @David If it helps, it does give that the lim inf of the ratio is 0. I do sympathise with the frustration though - I remember a similar feeling upon realising that $\sum a_n$ converging  didn't $\implies na_n\to0$ if $a_n\ge0$. The trick to prove it there was, as here, to introduce some irregularities at well-spaced intervals.

Comment: Right. It might help to know what might go wrong. Thanks!  It's a nice counterexample however annoying!